# Flutter Realtime Database [firebase_database/unknown] Could not convert

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the following error when trying to write data using firebase realtime database:

`[firebase_database/unknown] Could not convert`

> dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3       throw*
> packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/utils/utils.dart 92:5                  jsify
> packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/utils/utils.dart 80:36                 
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:7           forEach
> packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/utils/utils.dart 79:15                 jsify
> packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/database.dart 217:56                   update
> packages/firebase_database_web/src/database_reference_web.dart 69:23              update
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
> packages/firebase_database_web/src/database_reference_web.dart 67:22              update
> packages/firebase_database/src/database_reference.dart 120:22                     update
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 574:37  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 644:10  callMethod
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 648:5   dsend
> packages/myfinances/controllers/new_expense_controller.dart 42:26                 saveExpense
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
> packages/myfinances/controllers/new_expense_controller.dart 30:19                 saveExpense
> packages/myfinances/pages/new_expense_page.dart 272:21                            
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 275:24                              invokeCallback
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 652:11                                     handleTapUp
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 309:5                                      [_checkUp]
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 242:7                                      handlePrimaryPointer
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 630:9                               handleEvent
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 98:7                            [_dispatch]
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 143:9                           
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:7           forEach
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 141:17                          [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 127:7                           route
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 488:5                                  handleEvent
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 468:14                                 dispatchEvent
> packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 439:11                                dispatchEvent
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 413:7                                  [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 376:5                                  handlePointerEvent
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 323:7                                  [_flushPointerEventQueue]
> packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 292:9                                  [_handlePointerDataPacket]
> lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1289:5                                invoke1
> lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 273:5                                 invokeOnPointerDataPacket
> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 168:30                                    [_onPointerData]
> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 791:20                                    
> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 720:7                                     
> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 317:9                                     loggedHandler
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 574:37  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 579:39  dcall

code snippet:

```
class RequestReservationController {
  void addNewReservation(String name, DateTime date, int color) async {
    Reservation reservation = Reservation(name: name, date: DateUtils.dateOnly(date), color: color);
    String nameReservation = '${reservation.name}${reservation.date.day}${reservation.date.month}${reservation.date.year}';
   
    final reservationReference = FirebaseProvider().connection('/Reservations/$nameReservation');
    try{
      await reservationReference.update(reservation.toJson());
    }
    catch(error){
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(error);
      }
    }
  }
}

class FirebaseProvider{
  connection(String path){
    return FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(path);
  }
}
```

I have already written data using the realtime database on other occasions and it has always worked. This error only started to appear after updating Flutter to version `78.4.1`.